# Split string at character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, methods, split

I have three links :

```
"http//example.com/product/iphone?source=ac"
"http//example.com/product/samsung?source=tz"
"http//example.com/product/sony?source=sn"
```

I want to split the string to get two variables like so:

```
var link1 = 'http//example.com/product/iphone';
var link2 = '?source=ac'

// The others are similar
//var link1 = 'http//example.com/product/samsung';
//var link2 = '?source=tz'
//var link1 = 'http//example.com/product/sony';
//var link2 = '?source=sn'
```

Please give me your opinion, and help me in this case, I'm really new to javascript. It was difficult. Thank you everyone

Comment: Please share what you’ve tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex based approach using `match`:

```js
var urls = ["http://example.com/product/iphone?source=ac", "https://example.com/product/iphone"];
for (var i=0; i < urls.length; ++i) {
    var parts = urls[i].match(/https?:\/\/[^?]+|\?.*/g);
    console.log(urls[i] + "\nurl => " + parts[0] + ", query => " + parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lnk = "http//example.com/product/iphone?source=ac"


let n = lnk.indexOf("?")

host = lnk.slice(0,n)
source = lnk.slice(n,)

console.log(`host = ${host}`)
console.log(`source = ${source}` )
```

gives me the output

```
host = http//example.com/product/iphone
source = ?source=ac
```

should work with all links as ? is a common factor

or are you looking for regex solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to handle URLs properly:

```js
const path = "http://example.com/product/iphone?source=ac";

const { origin, pathname, search, hash } = new URL(path);

const link1 = origin + pathname;
const link2 = search + hash;

console.log(link1);
console.log(link2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the url and query?

```
let links = [
  "http//example.com/product/iphone?source=ac",
  "http//example.com/product/samsung?source=tz",
  "http//example.com/product/sony?source=sn"
]
links.forEach((x) => {
  let [ url, query ] = x.split("?")
  console.log(url, "?" + query)
})

// http//example.com/product/iphone ?source=ac
// http//example.com/product/samsung ?source=tz
// http//example.com/product/sony ?source=sn
```